# What's the meaning of 'head(-driven)' in HPSG?

Tags: terminology

In Head-driven phrase structure grammar or HPSG, what's the meaning of 'head'? Specifically, does the 'head' here mean the same thing as the term 'head' generally used in linguistics as follows?

> In linguistics, the **head** or **nucleus** of a phrase is the word that determines the syntactic category of that phrase. For example, the head of the noun phrase *boiling hot water* is the noun (**head noun**) *water*.
> <Wikipedia: [Head (linguistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_(linguistics)#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20the%20head%20or,semantic%20category%20of%20that%20compound.)>

If so, what's so special about HPSG in terms of the concept of 'head' vis-à-vis that of 'head' in general?

Also, what exactly does 'head-driven' mean in HPSG?

I believe that phrase structure grammar itself adopts the concept of 'head', so I wonder why those who created HPSG (Head-driven phrase structure grammar) decided to use the term 'head-driven' to distinguish HPSG from other types of 'phrase structure grammar' in general, when 'phrase structure grammar' was already 'head-driven', so to speak.

Comment: If you want to understand a framework you may need to actually look at a description of how it works, instead of trying to derive it entirely from the name.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Why do you assume that I'm "trying to derive it entirely from the name"? I have read through some of the descriptions, but still couldn't figure out why it's so named. Hence the question.

Comment: head-driven  means that in boiling hot water what "drives" the phrase is the noun water. Not the prepositioned adjuncts boiling hot.

Comment: @Lambie Thanks. So you're saying that 'head' in HPSG means the same thing as the 'head' normally referred to in linguistics other than HPSG. Then, I wonder why HPSG was so named when 'phrase structure grammar' before HPSG had been already 'head-driven', so to speak.

Comment: @JK2  I don't know the answer to that. Sorry.